# LDAP command which cancels the previous search

Tags: c#, ldap

I am using LDAP search whenever user does a key press. Which will cause lot of search in LDAP. For example if i am searching for user `Ann`, it will search for `A` then `An` and then `Ann`. Is there some command which will cancel previous search. If I press `Ann`, LDAP should stop searching for `An` and start new search for `Ann` immediately?

This is my code:

```cs
deSearch.Filter = String.Format(@"(|{0})", mysearchquery);

SearchResultCollection myresults = deSearch.FindAll();
```

Comment: A different approach achieving a similar effect would be to limit how often you send the command instead. I.e. only search when there is a minimum 3 characters and a new keystroke has not occurred in 0.3s

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way to measure elapsed time between keystrokes in javascript? My call actually goes from a web page using javascript, ajax and then to the controller

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should cancel the previous LDAP operation using the Abandon operation (which has no results, so you cannot be sure it's been abandoned), or the Cancel Extended operation for those servers that are supporting it (OpenDJ, OpenLDAP...).

The idea of introducing a short delay before sending the request is also a best practice.